# How to calculate the force applied by a magnetorquer on a piece of a perfect ferromagnetic material?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields

Magnetorquer are 3 axis electromagnets used in satellites for attitude control using Earth's magnetic field. How to calculate the force applied by a magnetorquer on a piece of a perfect ferromagnetic material at a particular distance in a vacuum given that I know the actuation (in Am<sup>2</sup>).
In my case, I'm trying to calculate the force applied by [this](https://www.isispace.nl/product/isis-magnetorquer-board/) electromagnet on a piece of iron placed at a distance of 50 mm from one of the poles of the electromagnet when the current flows through the coils is 1 ampere.

https://www.isispace.nl/product/isis-magnetorquer-board/

Answer (score 0):

Force on a ferro-magenetic piece of material placed at distance `s` from pole of the electromagnet with actuation `M` carrying current `I` is given by

`F = (M*I*u)/(2*(s^2))`

Here, `u= magnetic permeability of the medium`, e.g. in vaccum `u = magnetic constant`

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/253179) to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Please [edit] your answer accordingly. Thanks!